# Effecient way to add default user to model object which is created by other users

Tags: django, django-models

My `User` has 2 objects.

```
1. admin - super admin
2. tom - user
```

`MyModel` with

```
class MyModel:
    project_user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Let's suppose `tom` is creating a `MyModel` object:

```
MyModel(project_user=request.user).save()
```

Here I would like to add `admin` user automatically to the `project_user` object when someone creates an object. What will the more efficient way to implement it,How about using signals or `def save(self)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/).

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

In the snippet above, I'm trying to create a custom model (i.e. Profile) when a default user once created.
Therefore, I think you could write like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def create_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        User.objects.create_user(username=instance.username)
```

And [create_user()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) is a helper function of Django.

Edit: Added what I import in the snippet.